# Selenium-Asserting the presence of multiple keywords of an array in a List

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, assert

Trying to check the presence of multiple keywords in a list.

```
List<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("Sam Mayers test");
array.add("");
array.add("value");
array.add("");
array.add("");
array.add("");
array.add("District 49");
array.add("Till the last test");
array.add("Dawn Strings");
array.add("Lists value");
array.add("");
array.add("");
array.add("Total Hits Lists");
array.add("Values");


Boolean found = false;

        List<String> keywords_tobe_checked = new ArrayList<>();
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("Lists");
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("value");
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("Mayers");
        List<String> dummylist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            String val = array.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < keywords_tobe_checked.size(); j++) {
            if (val.indexOf(keywords_tobe_checked.get(j)) >= 0) {
                dummylist.add(val);
            }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dummylist);

        Assert.assertTrue(dummylist.containsAll(keywords_tobe_checked), "Its not correct");
```

My above code is failing on the asserttrue condition and giving me an incorrect result.

Is there a way i could pass this assertion by the condition that all the keywords mentioned in the "keywords_tobe_checked" are appearing in the "dummylist"?

Updated Code tried:

```
List<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
        array.add("Sam Mayers test");
        array.add("");
        array.add("value");
        array.add("");
        array.add("");
        array.add("");
        array.add("District 49");
        array.add("Till the last test");
        array.add("Dawn Strings");
        array.add("Lists value");
        array.add("");
        array.add("");
        array.add("Total Hits Lists");
        array.add("Values");



        List<String> keywords_tobe_checked = new ArrayList<>();
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("Lists");
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("value");
        keywords_tobe_checked.add("Mayers");

        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println(keywords_tobe_checked);
        for (String keyword : keywords_tobe_checked) {
            Boolean found = false;  
            for (String value : array) {
                if (value.contains(keyword)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                Assert.assertTrue(found, "The keyword " + keyword + " not in the list");
            }

        }


 Content of the Array------------       [Sam Mayers test, , value, , , , District 49, Till the last test, Dawn Strings, Lists value, , , Total Hits Lists, Values]
  Content of the Keywords to be checked -----------------  [Lists, value, Mayers]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: The keyword Lists not in the list expected [true] but found [false]
        at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
        at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:496)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking if `List` contains `String` the result will be true only when there is an exact match

```
array.contains("Lists"); // false

array.contains("Lists value"); // true
```

To check partial match you need to use the `Assert.assertTrue` inside the loop

```
for (String keyword : keywords_tobe_checked) {
    boolean hasKeyword = false;
    for (String value : array) {
        if (value.contains(keyword)) {
            hasKeyword = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    Assert.assertTrue(hasKeyword, "The keyword " + keyword + " is in the list");
}
```

Comment: I can't edit your post.
Your answer is correct, you are just missing `}` after `break;`

Comment: Not exactly working as i want.... Again getting an assertion failure as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: The keyword Lists not in the list expected [true] but found [false]"

Comment: @Guy I have added the updated code i tried using your given logic but still its throwing me an assertion failure.

Comment: @Automation_User What are the values in `dummylist` when you run it? also, did you copy the strings from somewhere? there might be encoding difference, try to write them manually.

Comment: @Automation_User Make sure you are using code with missing `}` as the previous version throws `AssertionError`

Comment: @Guy ... Please check the update .... I have printed the output as well as the corrected code, Its failing on the assertion

Comment: @Automation_User I don't see the content of `dummylist`. Did you try to type manually (instead of copy paste) the values of `keywords_tobe_checked` and `array`?

Comment: @Guy Please ignore dummylist as i was trying it earlier for refinement.... I am only using the raw array now whose contents i have added in the updated code section and yes the updated code is the manually type value.

Comment: @Automation_User I only asked about `dummylist` to check if `indexOf` works. You can try `if (value.indexOf(keyword) != -1)` instead of `if (value.contains(keyword))`. By the way, is there any more code? are you manipulating the lists in some other place?

Comment: @Guy yep had tried indexOf method initially but that too is failing .... I guess my question isn't clear enough, The problem is bcz i am trying to check for the array of keywords which have partial occurence in the raw array.

Comment: @Automation_User Try replacing `Boolean found = false;` with `boolean found = false;` `boolean` should start with lower case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147067/discussion-between-automation-user-and-guy).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code is not correct due to values in Array List.

While using `containsAll` method you are looking for SPECIFIC String in Array List.

Example:
The 1st list has object `Sam Mayers test`.
The 2nd list has object `Mayers`.

This is why you have AssertionError. `Sam Mayers test` and `Mayers` are totally two different objects.