# Selenium - Java - how to assert/verify all links on a page are working, get title and verify against expected titles

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, pageobjects

I am new to test automation and i am currently working on a personal project

I have this method in which it finds all the links for a section on the page, clicks on each link, irritates through each tab and then gets the title of each page

However, i want a way to verify the titles of these links against a list of expected titles

What would be the best approach to modify this in order to do this? would it be better to store in an array and then assert/verify each title separately?

I have tried a few ways to assert by changes return type to String and also to List but with no luck

```
public void linksAreWorkingDashBoardLeftPanal() throws Exception {

    List<WebElement> li_All = links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(int i = 0; i < li_All.size(); i++){

        String clickOnLinkTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
        links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickOnLinkTab);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }

    //Opens all the tabs
    Set<String> getTitleinWindow = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    Iterator<String> it = getTitleinWindow.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {

          driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
```

Comment: Store titles in a `list` and your expected titles in a different `list` and iterate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628447/selenium-asserting-the-presence-of-multiple-keywords-of-an-array-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the while loop as follows;

```
List<String> expectedTitleList = new ArrayList<>(); 
// Get the expected titles in a list. 
// You have to initiate and add expected titles to this list, before running the while loop.

List<String> actualTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
          driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
          actualTitleList.add(driver.getTitle());
    }

// Create copies of each list;
Set<String> expectedSet = new HashSet<>(expectedTitleList);
Set<String> actualSet = new HashSet<>(actualTitleList);

Set<String> expectedOnlySet = new HashSet<>(expectedSet);
Set<String> actualOnlySet = new HashSet<>(actualSet);

expectedOnlySet.removeAll(actualSet);
actualOnlySet.removeAll(expectedSet);

// Check if expectedOnlySet and actualOnlySet are empty
// If both of them are empty then all titles are received as expected.

boolean isEmpty = (expectedOnlySet.size() == 0 && actualOnlySet.size() == 0);

if (expectedOnlySet.size() > 0 || actualOnlySet.size() > 0) {
   // If expectedOnlySet contain any title; it means those titles are not opened in the browser.

   // If actualOnlySet contain any title; it means those titles are not expected titles.
   StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

   for (String x: expectedOnlySet) {
       message.append("Did not receive: ");
       message.append(x).append(", ");
   }

   for (String y: actualOnlySet) {
       message.append("Not expected but received: ");
       message.append(y).append(", ");
   }

   Assert.assertTrue(false, message,toString());
}else {
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

Here you can use removeAll() method in Collections. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

We have to check both scenarios;

1. Whether all expected titles are received
2. All received titles are expected

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I took what i needed from your code and it worked perfectly.

this work and i added my own assertion

```
    List<WebElement> li_All = links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(int i = 0; i < li_All.size(); i++){

        String clickOnLinkTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
        links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickOnLinkTab);

        }//Opens all the tabs 
        Set<String> getTitleinWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = getTitleinWindow.iterator();

        // Get the expected titles in a list. 
        // You have to initiate and add expected titles to this list, before running the while loop.

        List<String> expectedTitleList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 1 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 2 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 3 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 4 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 5 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 6 title");
        expectedTitleList.add("Page 7 title");

        List<String> actualTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
           while(it.hasNext())
         {
                driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
                actualTitleList.add(driver.getTitle());
         }

        //System.out.println(expectedTitleList);
        // System.out.println(actualTitleList); 

    if(actualTitleList.equals(expectedTitleList)).....
```